# Having problems with RewriteRule and .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm having a problem with my .htaccess. This is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks

#Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#Profile
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3
```

I want to remove the .php extension, and create a seo-friendly URL with /profile.php. The problem comes when I try to access to http://website.com/profile/1/2/3, **I get 500 Error**. But if I remove the code which removes php extension, then, *it works well*, but of course, the .php extension is showed.

So... what's wrong in this code? I checked over and over and I really don't find any bugs... thanks.

Comment: The order of rules is important, as is stopping the rewrite process with `[L]` if you don't want them to interfere.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is not using `L` flag (marking Last rule).

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

#Profile
RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?one=$1&two=$2&three=$3 [L,QSA]

#Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: +1 the order could be interfering here. And, OP is trying the URL as `/profile/1/2/3` but his rule seems to expect `/profile/\d-\d/\d` (not exactly but notice the `-`).

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: Thanks and Very good point. OP please note the difference in your regex and your URL. I am editing my answer to support your example URL.